# Global .zip file

Tags: php, zip, global

Is it possible to use a wild card to open/unzip a .zip file?

I have tried using global(*.zip) but it doesn't unzip the files enclosed in that zip file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$archive = new ZipArchive($file);
foreach (glob('*.zip') as $file) {
  $archive->open($file);
  $archive->extractTo('.');
  $archive->close();
}
```

Typically wildcards are used to match against multiple files. In this case all are extracted.